# Code Contract C# ensure value is in array

Tags: c#

This is most likely very simple but I can't seem to figure it out:)

I have 2 arrays of int.
I want to make sure one value is in both arrays using code contracts in some form.
If the value is not both arrays I don't want to continue

Can this be done? 
I was thinking of something like this but can't seem to get it to work

```
Contract.Requires(g[variable ] == y[variable])
```

The value must be in the same posion in both arrays

This is what I have now

```
 private static int FirstCut(int[] g, int[] h)
        {
            int x = 0;

            Contract.Requires(g.Length > 0);            
            Contract.Requires(g.Length == h.Length); //skal være lige lange

            while (g[x] != h[x])
            {
                x++;
            } 
            return x;
        }
```

Regards

Birger

Comment: You say "both arrays", but you only have one array -- `g`.

Comment: Just to try to clarify. I don't kow how to enter variable.
I'm pretty sure it can be done like this in java  
ensures g[\result]==h[\result];

Answer (score 1):

```
Contract.Requires(g[variable ] == g[variable])
```

Well that is only one array and, even if it were two, that would require they be found at the same index as well, which you did not say is a requirement.  It seems to me as though the condition should be:

```
x.Contains(variable) && y.Contains(variable)
```

Assuming `x` and `y` are of the type `int[]`.

Also, I know nothing about code contracts in C# or what the performance implications of performing two O(n) operations at the top of your method would be.

Comment: my mistake.. copy/paste error
what should the variable be? the value should be in the same index in both arrays.

Comment: Code contracts Ensures calls are analyzed statically; they're not executed at run time.

Comment: @phoog: Interesting.  How could that be considering the contents of these arrays could not possibly be known at compile time?  There is no way this expression could be evaluated then.  I do realize that these are probably disabled in release builds though.

Comment: If `x` and `y` each come out of a method with `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int[]>().Contains(variable))` then they can go into a method with `Contract.Requires(x.Contains(variable) && y.Contains(variable))` -- it's pretty cool, though in practice I get frustrated by the fact that many framework methods lack contract annotations.

Comment: @phoog You state that Code Contracts are not ran during execution time, but this statement is incorrect. You can check a setting in the project properties to check Code Contracts during runtime as well.

Comment: @Xilconic you are right.  Furthermore, if you check that box, you can select options that can enable or disable runtime checking of postconditions.

Answer (score 0):

If the value should be on the same index, assuming both `g` and `y` are `int[]` and `variable` is `int`, wouldn't that be something like:

```cs
Contract.Requires(g.Contains(variable) && g.IndexOf(variable) == y.IndexOf(variable))
```

*Disclaimer: Totally untested and maybe I'm not understanding the question*

Comment: that goes through `g` twice and `y` once for every item that doesn't exist.  You could do better, performance wise.  You can just store the result of one of the `indexOf` calls and check the value at that index in the other array.  The `Contains` and `indexOf` on the same variable and same array is also just redundant.

Comment: Well, yes, but this is aiming Code Contracts, which don't really need to be performant (since production code will usually "disable" the checks), plus, one is encouraged to write short, readable (and not necessarily performant) expressions for Code Contracts.

Comment: Well it's just redundant.  It's not like you're adding complexity, you're removing it to increase performance.  It's win-win.

Comment: @Servy , I'd still go this way for a Code Contract, instead of writing an unrolled loop... you could also use `Contract.Requires(g.IndexOf(variable) != -1 && g.IndexOf(variable) == y.IndexOf(variable));` but that'd still do redundant iterations. I can't seem to find a way to do this without writing code before the `Contract.Requires` statement, which is just not allowed (unless you are using `EndContractBlock()`, which is allowed, yet discouraged).

Comment: And of course, you could store the first return of `IndexOf()`, but again, that'd require a previous expression to the contract. As per `Contract.Requires` documentation: *This method call must be at the beginning of a method or property, before any other code.* ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412847.aspx))

Comment: Easy fix.  Just refactor the whole thing out into a method, then there is no code outside of a Code Contract block.  Just verify that the return value of the method call is true/false or whatever

Comment: @Servy, although you are indeed right, I'd still say that doing this kind of refactoring and adding new methods **just** for doing a code contract for this is a bit overengineering (again, code contracts won't go into production code). Of course this is only my oppinion (and again, you are absolutely right on your appreciations).

Comment: I would discourage the general practice of, "Force task X to be all a part of a single statement just so I can use it, without a helper method, in a code contract"  You're trying to do too much in one line; it should be several.  Since you need to have a single expression for the result, you should refactor the code into a method (VS does this with just a few clicks).  The use of Code Contracts doesn't all of a sudden mean you through out these well established principles.  Performance aside, this logic belongs in a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length && i < secondArray.Length; i++)
{
  if(firstArray[i] == mySearchValue &&  secondArray[i] == mySearchValue)
  {
    //whatever you want to do

    break; //you can remove this if you don't want to stop the loop.
  }
}
```

Comment: sure it can do this way.. But was looking for some way to do this in code contract

Comment: @Birger You can just set a boolean `isFound` in the loop and use the Code Contract to check the results at the end.

Comment: I've just added som basic code in the first post.
The loop will never stop unless I'm sure the same value is in both arrays at the same spot

Comment: @Birger So for your loop there you should add a `&& x < g.Length` to the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Having played a fair bit with Code Contracts during my senior year, this is how id consider solving your problem. It looks a bit cleaner than some of the posted solutions.

```
public static int FirstCut(int[] g, int[] h)
{
    Contract.Requires(h.Length == g.Length);
    Contract.Requires(Contract.Exists(0, g.Length, x => g[x] == h[x]));

    //Do whatever knowing that 2 values at index x in the arrays are the same
}
```